# JSON Deserialization error in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to deserialize some JSON which I got from the eBay API but I am getting the error: `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.String out of START_ARRAY token`

The JSON that is returned has many levels to it. e.g.

`{"searchResult":[{"@count":"100","item":[{"itemId":["281492499859"],"title":["Panasonic Lumix TZ20 Digital Camera in Good Condition"],...` etc

This is for a property called `itemId` in `CompletedListing` (class defined below)

I am calling this method with the line:

```
CompletedListingContainer listing = mapper.readValue(new File("C:\\resource\\jsonresult.txt"), CompletedListingContainer.class);`
```

Here are my classes.

**CompletedListingContainer**

```
public class CompletedListingContainer {

  private ArrayList<CompletedListing> item;

  private ArrayList<SearchResult> searchResult;

  private List<String> paginationOutput;

  @JsonIgnore
  public List<String> getPaginationOutput() {
      return paginationOutput;
  }

  public ArrayList<SearchResult> getSearchResult() {
      return searchResult;
  }

  public ArrayList<CompletedListing> getItem() {
      return item;
  } 
}
```

**SearchResult**

```
public class SearchResult {

  @JsonProperty("@count")
  private String count;

  private ArrayList<CompletedListing> item;

  @JsonIgnore
  public String getCount() {
      return count;
  }

  public ArrayList<CompletedListing> getItem() {
      return item;
  }
}
```

**CompletedListing**

```
public class CompletedListing {

  @JsonProperty("itemId")
  private String itemId;

  private String title;

  @JsonProperty("itemId")
  public String getItemId() {
    return itemId;
  }

  @JsonProperty("title")
  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need any more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`{"itemId":["281492499859"]` means your `CompletedListing.itemId` property should be a list or array.

Comment: Thanks, this was the problem. I didn't realise it needed to be a `List`.

Comment: @JamesFox glad to help, please note that same goes for `title`

Comment: Yes, I am changing for all the properties as I have more that I didn't add to the question.

Answer (score 0):

put `private ArrayList<CompletedListing> item` in your `SearchResult` class and remove it from `CompletedListingContainer`

look at your json file structure:

```
{
   "searchResult":[
       {
        "count":"100",
        "item":[
               {"itemId":["281492499859"]...
       },
   ....
}
```

try this [online tool](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to generate Java classes from json

Comment: This hasn't fixed the issue but I can see that it was wrong to have that in the `CompletedListingContainer` class.